# SQL how to simplify this query and increase performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Have this query that I guess can be written in a more simple way that will perform better:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productid)
FROM productwords pw
WHERE productid IN
(SELECT productid FROM productwords pw JOIN words w 
  ON pw.wordid = w.id WHERE word = 'nike')
AND productid IN 
(SELECT productid FROM productwords pw JOIN words w 
  ON pw.wordid = w.id WHERE word = 'free')
```

Goal of the query is to get the number of distinct productids that have words = both 'nike' and 'free'.

Thanks!

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Please post your table structure and some sample data...

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should be better just using a `join`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productid)
FROM productwords pw
   JOIN words w ON pw.productid = w.id 
WHERE word IN ('nike','free')
```

Your current query `on pw = w.id` isn't actually correct.  Whichever field you are attempting to `join` on should be included above.  I guessed `productid`, but perhaps its `wordid` instead...

Comment: I think this query returns a count of products that matches *either* of the keywords. This may be what OP intended, but I read the specification a little differently... return a count... but include *only* those products that match keyword 'nike' AND matche keyword 'free'. (If a product matches 'nike' but doesn't match 'free', then that product would not be included.)

Comment: You are right, the returned products must be the ones that match both keywords, i.e. both "nike" AND "free".

Comment: I have fixed the error in "on pw = w.id" - it should be "on pw.wordid = w.id"

Answer (score 0):

you can simply the query by doing like this

```
select count(*), w.word from product p left join words w on w.id = p.word_id where w.name = 'nike' or w.name = 'free' group by w.name
```

hope this query answer your question.
you could also filter by

```
where w.name in ('nike', 'free')
```

if you have many rows (let's say 10,000++) you could improve like this

```
SELECT count(*), w.name from product p JOIN (select id, name from words where name = 'nike' or name = 'free') w on w.id = p.word_id group by w.name
```

Comment: This is indeed a somewhat simpler query. But this also returns a result significantly *different* than the result of the OP query. This returns a count of rows related to each `word`. This may be the result OP is wanting, but I read the specification quite differently, returning an equivalent of the OP query.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to insert the filters. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange that the foreign key column in the `productswords` (product swords?) table is named `pw`, and not `word_id`. (But it's just a column name, we can name it whatever we want. If the foreign key is actually named something else, then replace `pw.pw` in the queries below with `pw.column_name` ...)

To find products that match both of the two words, meaning, only return a product if it matches the word 'nike' AND if it matches the word 'free'...

We can use a join operation, combined with a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause...

```
 SELECT pw.productid 
   FROM productwords pw
   JOIN words w 
     ON w.id = pw.pw
    AND w.word IN ('nike','free')   -- keywords to match
  GROUP BY pw.productid
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.word) = 2  -- number of keywords to match
```

To get just a count, we can wrap that in query in parens and reference it as an inline view...

```
 SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM ( SELECT pw.productid 
            FROM productwords pw
            JOIN words w 
              ON w.id = pw.pw
             AND w.word IN ('nike','free')   -- keywords you are looking for
           GROUP BY pw.productid
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.word) = 2  -- number of keywords to match
        ) v
```

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

For example, using an **`EXISTS (correlated subquery)`** pattern to get only the products that match BOTH of the specified words...

```
 SELECT pw.productid
   FROM productwords pw
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM words w
                  WHERE w.id = pw.pw      -- related to row on outer query
                    AND w.word IN ('nike','free')
               )
 GROUP BY pw.productid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pw.pw) = 2
```

To get just a count, again, wrap that in parens and reference it as an inline view.

---

For non-trivial sets, having suitable indexes available can *significantly* improve performance of both queries. For example

```
   ... ON productswords (pw, productid)
   ... ON words (word, id)
```